# Check if a list of other strings is %LIKE% another string

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

Is there a short way to check if a list of strings is %LIKE% a given string?

For example:

book
animal
a

Would all satisfy this condition for "A Book about Animals"?

I know that I could write out Title Like '%book%' AND '%animal%' LIKE Title, etc. but that seems unwieldy.

I'm using this for an autocomplete, where I return results where every word is in the result.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the syntax of the `LIKE` operator.

Comment: just typed it out wrong.. fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mate... make the searchable columns into "fulltext" colums and then do

`SELECT * FROM books WHERE MATCH(fulltext_column) AGAINST('animal book a')`

best way. :) see http://devzone.zend.com/article/1304

Comment: Does it make sense to use FULLTEXT search on an autocomplete?  I would think you need perfect %LIKE% precision on an autocomplete..

Comment: for what you want. You don't want perfect precision - you want to be able to match the words in any order - like is too restrictive for that.

Comment: My concern is that FULLTEXT has limitation like stopwords, min length, etc. While LIKE is perfect in precision.. so i was thinking itd be better fit for autocomplete

Comment: You can edit the stop word list using the ft_stopword_file variable (or set it to '' to index all words as long or longer than ft_min_word_len) if that suits your needs better. You can also change the minimum indexed word length using the ft_min_word_len variable, which exists for the same reason. (taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320838/mysql-fulltext-stopwords-rationale)

Comment: Problem with doing that is that I use FULLTEXT elsewhere on the site, where I do want those options set that way

Comment: google? I don't know, you're getting into unknown territory here haha. Anyway, the min word limit is 4 characters, are users really going to hit on specific options with less than 4 characters? if you use `MATCH(column) AGAINST('+search +terms +preceeded +with +plus +signs' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` then you will include all search terms. So just replace all " "s with " +" :)

Comment: I would want the autocomplete to work with words shorter than 4.. I realize now that my unwieldy LIKE way is the only option.  I'll check your answer as correct though just because it would work with most people

Answer (score 0):

You should look at http://lucene.apache.org/solr/, it let's you index your data, and then can give a REST API that you can call to populate an autocomplete dropdown.

Comment: thanks for the tip.. right now though i'm kind of on a deadline so i'd like to get this working with mysql

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you have two options:

1) Perform a query with lots of WHERE clauses like you have.

2) Maintain a copy of the column with all of the words sorted. Then you can sort the search tokens and perform the query:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Title_sorted LIKE "%a%animal%book%"
```

Comment: And yes, you can also use SOLR, but in the absence of that you can do option (2) listed.

Comment: Option 2  requires the 3 words in that order.

Comment: Sorry I didn't reply to this a while ago. There's a reason you maintain a separate, sorted column ;)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a full-text search index, I recommend you look into that to get efficient results. Going with Lucene might be overkill for just an autocomplete.

Comment: Does it make sense to use FULLTEXT search on an autocomplete? I would think you need perfect %LIKE% precision on an autocomplete..